# Simplify a filter function that should check all string and number values in an object via a search string query

Tags: typescript

I have an object that contains fields of different types such as strings, numbers etc.

I have a string that I get from a search box that I want to use and filter out above objects, based on that string and all the objects fields that is of type string and number. Currently I have:

```
function filterJobsBySearchQuery(searchString: string) {
    if (!Jobs?.orders) {
      return;
    }
    searchString.toLowerCase();

    //simplify this? Preferably all string values in jobs.orders should be checked
    const filterRemoteJobs = Jobs?.orders.filter((item) => {
      return  item.jobID.toString().includes(searchString) || item.jobDescription?.toLowerCase().includes(searchString) ||
      item.activationMethod?.toLowerCase().includes(searchString) || item.jobStatusDescription?.toLowerCase().includes(searchString)
      || item.status?.toLowerCase().includes(searchString);
    });
    return filterRemoteJobs;
  }
```

While it works, the code seems very repeating as we are manually checking all the (string, and converting number to string) fields in the object which seems uneccessary. Is there any way to simplify the code? Full code:

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAUiARhAXPJEYF4YG8CwAUDDCAE4AmApmajANpEkkHHMkCGAZl1cFFQoA5ENSEcAtlTqM27Fk3nsukgJYAbAJ5oAjAA4ANIqUkomgA5U0AJiNyT5kBFVRV4NAAZj8gL7eSALp2SgBWSACSACK6Oh4ALAl6OsHyHPyqAG4cruAAslRQABaiaADkAEoAogDCACqV5aUp7GRUAI4ArtICZOJSZeW1Tf4w3aoS2YIAgulZOWC141Yw1gDsHgBszcwA7uQA1kIdEog0ZUIAtHrD9iTUHOpnMKUeO1Q7G6sbN0rQ2R10UoABTIIAA5mRJBJVGAwT95GFEJFpMAyKpzPMygBVcwUSbw9iIgDKUH%20EGREFR6MxzwA8gBpAnMECWSHzClUjFuMBoMAddTqbYkFk0bLcoEcSFSHq8-mCkZ8k40WlcGauObcui2Ea0HYUdRE4BUMCSty1CzLUoAGXGLmmWQ0HEQjyZJAgxooi36MDA7xgkUmAApStYPKGLjprBcPABOWo6DYoACsMZQHg8pQAlEKYOoONAcXiBLTKE9fTt-UGQ2GPBGo7H43oUDpUwBmOIAOj0qx0We8Pm2rCU3F4-EEIjEkmkaFkJjwI2Uai0uhz7DMlhXC%20YjmcNK8t2YA63Q7nMBU0OXMH0q%20Y6%20W2oP7B3Lm5ni3R8f88-JHPGm0V4fU8YDvTdvxgZ893fEYghGREol0BJVlbHM0nVMU8gKYoKAGGp6kaHNWk6boaD6S1BldUZoHGSYKDVTJ0IWJYbCTaxkJGPYyEOY5TjIc5rhze5Hl455002L4KL%20KAATKIEPRhOEc0RDk0S5dxng6XF8UUpASTJZTqVfZ4gSqAB9aoAAkanpEyGQokU2W5fTVJ5H05RzeyGIlKUCjLNyFW45VVVmBitQIiA9QNI0TTREBzQ3Z4bWhARaIdPNnSoCSPS9ZZy0rARg1DcNI2jOME2TVN0yzHM8wLTTi1LYTcoDfLqyK%20tStWcqUDiHQO3iPt7A-dgT3YEc%20GSicqFImRjy3H8l3-SMb1MC1QKAiDDP3Oc-APGCDzg6IryTOIky2HV2i6aASKnAYhhQ4L5nyIoSmeKo6gaCixgmZK6I1cBspiVsYxzDiuKVYTSiEJN%20JGQSnhedNPm%20HNJOk16%20AeR4KAopSURUmlSnCGANKLDLtMQXSpPJPGDLU4FTIsqybMZdzWQYpyaT5AVWdFeYvKnGVXO5-zwZVX6QrW%20RdX1Q1jVNWLVoS20ftSp0XRRrKmJ9P1mqoAqazrEr40TFM0wzbMRhqqBC0mEtqEanWq0K2tiobHROqB7qkw7VYYxjAb2B2wIUlADowCgNAkyIHwAG4iCILgw-ScAzw0HoEGQQN3UlYBChJNFYTQaAC7BTMv3YVQuBgQMAEIM8wAAfBuYBr7OyFz-P5LLkbmFaKSyDAOPBvjuRvFASBYC4NOaEEAAhTQiSoHPCmwVP1HTjB58X5eAEUujITQs6X9u86gEvMyH3uCg6Ae156OeF%20P3PL5gHaR8TsBk7AO%20aHrren8KHvGgh824dzPvJIu4DYTd28JXaudcMAAH4OzkHthAGBB4%20430Hv2bwoDT4lw7FAEAVoQBvDINUfMesL4j3YAAejoc4CQ5h1CV00MBQoqgICIJgCCKgvBITOnYZjGAxd5IwCyOoS6MAYQwERBAFBDVMAQGKPyCgMBTgwFznwfYggx7gGgD-Mg5QqASBAAIeuq967INQTQBRU9140EDIGO0Egy5YAAHzlyltfW%20MiBASA7AdIhIBO6wkDJmDsMJgBSOoBAI%20y8wmlxgE3fxpiglIA5tyZBxDSHkMoe6CJUTP6xOkAkk%20SSy5NxGK4jsqF6KPUwqIHJJCyE0AKdQ4pMSOhxPKWA8%20KTm61OJKSKmWTwAtLye0qhRTomlPifgypIxUm1NRtwkJUyKEzMiXMnpZTFlQNLi-EgPgaH2CwbfBxPQTFmIsRgF%20b82DjwgCAR4HZ1DgkDFc3%20GBgwk3xJmM5TAR4wh6CoI06BkDeOFEotAGc7Y0HoAEY5WiQBhwjq5cGQ8dqgpoOCqgkKEVkGhTAMaY5hCiCmlObhaAOBgE0EilF9S-pgCelhRBkCS5MoetybKHK8oEublzdQKLc75mcBAI44N%20ViNhKKwo4quGLzRNIGVhyUVwzIGqrl3gvo0XFvMPlsosXeFxpSfG2TOXyRRQdY1PEbU6VGQCcZYBtXWu8FbG29V7b8t1iixUPExY8oMfygNNAUlCxFd4Dy7IabOTdbCCNwqUUxvFJKAWNAE1giTXKFNDUoihoCmQFF5hWhTHMKWkAkiVTVAVWQMES9EAaBcJofliAQCvKXjg85F1iK9CnFmlF0tIpyxinFKgg68GaykL6yYKK1mTvsBkGEi72CgylTxRdPggA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```js
function filterJobsBySearchQuery(searchString: string) {
    if (!Jobs?.orders) {
        return
    }

    const keys = [
        'jobID',
        'jobDescription',
        'activationMethod',
        'jobStatusDescription',
        'status',
    ] as const
    
    const filterRemoteJobs = Jobs?.orders.filter((item) => {
        return keys.some((key) =>
          item[key].toString().includes(searchString.toLowerCase())
        )
    })

    return filterRemoteJobs
}
```